# phone number field in advanced custom field on wordpress

Tags: validation, advanced-custom-fields

how to validate phone number field in advanced custom field on wordpress.Minimum number and maximum number and type only number.

/^(\d[\s-]?)?[([\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[)]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to develop your own code, you can use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/validated-field-for-acf/) and then use RegEx to define the allowed phone number pattern for example:

```
/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i
```

This pattern will work for a range of phone numbers but you can adapt the RegEx to your specific requirements. There already is a post on phone number validation at: 
[A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

I hope this helps.

Comment: how to use RegEx?